# Python trying to iterate over one element of multidimensional list

Tags: python, arrays

I've searched high and low but am struggling with the following code. In the for loop at the bottom, I need to iterate through the names in the first element of the mutlidimensional list. I'm very new to Python so please excuse my ignorance.

```
for file in files: # loop thru each recording
  file_with_path = recording_fullpath + "/" + file  #construct full file path
  file_mtime = modification_date(file_with_path)  # obtain file mod date
  if file_mtime >= start_date and file_mtime <= end_date:
#print file + " is within the time range " + str(file_mtime)
archive_list[count].append (file_with_path)
archive_list[count].append (recording_subdir) # append filename with path to list
archive_list.append([])
count =+ 1

tarname = tar_path + "/" + client_id + "_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + ".tar.gz"
print tarname
tar = tarfile.open (tarname, "w:gz")
for name in archive_list[][]:
  print "Adding %s" % (name)
  tar.add(name, arcname=client_id)
tar.close()
```

This code works when I just use a single element array but can't work out the syntax to include the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tarname = tar_path + "/" + client_id + "_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + ".tar.gz"
print tarname
tar = tarfile.open (tarname, "w:gz")
for name, dir in archive_list:
  print "Adding %s" % (name)
  tar.add(name, arcname=client_id)
tar.close()
```

This iterates over the list, unpacking every two-elements sublist into two variables, `name` and `dir`.

Comment: Thanks for that, have updated the for loop. It now reads as per your example, however now the script is throwing an error "too many values to unpack"

Comment: @btongeorge: That's because you always have an empty sublist at the end. To be honest, I'd replace the three `append()s` with just `archive_list.append([file_with_path, recording_subdir])`.

Comment: OK thanks, done that. Now I get an error "need more than 0 values to unpack"

Comment: One thing I notice - when I print the list of lists, I see a blank entry at the beginning: `[[], ['/home/gm/testrecordings/0139*123/file3.wav', '0139*123'], ['/home/gm/testrecordings/0139*123/file1.wav', '0139*123'], ['/home/gm/testrecordings/0139*123/file2.wav', '0139*123'], ['/home/gm/testrecordings/0139*123/file4.wav', '0139*123']]
`

Comment: @btongeorge: You are adding that empty element somewhere. You need to find and fix that.

Comment: I initialise the array like so `archive_list = [[]]` - is this the problem perhaps?

Comment: @btongeorge: Yes it is. Change that to `archive_list = []`.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help. All working as it should and I've learned from it.